# Copy CD contents from cd storage server to network share

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, copy, impersonation

I need to write a webapp (asp.net MVC) that copies the contents from a CD to a network share (eg. Z:\dir1). All servers are in the same domain.
Process flow is as follows:
- User inserts CD-ROM into cdserver1 (PrimeArray ProServer 3802 XT)
- CD contents is copied to internal HDD automatically
- User enters CD information in the webapp
- This info will serve to construct the network share path (eg. Z:\dir1\userdata1\userdata2)
- Check periodically if CD contents is copied to internal HDD of cdserver1
- Copy CD contents from internal HDD of cdserver1 to network share

The parts I haven't figured out:
- How to access the internal HDD of cdserver1 from asp.net (eg. //cdserver1/cdrom1/)
- How to check periodically if cd contents is copied (ajax, jquery)
- How to access the network share from asp.net
- What about user rights (impersonation, NETWORK SERVICE account, ...)

A whole bunch, I know :-)
Any ideas or thoughts on this are more than welcome.
Thanks in advance,
Stijn

Comment: Is the CD-ROM on the same machine as the server?

Comment: Is anyone still looking for an answer here? If so, Is the CD-ROM on the same machine as the server?